# ESP32 & Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy, esp32

I'm currently looking into how to set up a sense network made from ESP32s to track BLE tokens in an area, but I'm stuck at the first step... Getting Bluetooth & device listing to work on the ESP32, as I couldn't find usable documentation about it.

The idea is to gather signal strength info for the token(s) with the sensor network and forward the data through WiFi with MQTT to a central processing unit which in turn will overlay the calculated positions on a map.

Could anyone help me out with getting BT listing to work?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the actual question is not about the IoT goal, but rather about a basic initial step of ESP32 software development.  Example code will likely be your best resource, however requests to find example code and other external resources are generally considered off-topic throughout the SE system of sites.

Comment: Could you be more specific about getting Bluetooth and device listing to work? An explanation as to where you are so far as using Bluetooth with the ESP32 and what you mean by "stuck at the first step" would be helpful.

Comment: This may help https://esp32.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=1377 as well as this http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Use-BluetoothBLE-With-ESP32/ which says that "the software support for using Bluetooth is missing. (It's under development)" though I am unsure as to the date of this information.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I can only agree, but there are already a couple of device specific questions floating around...

Comment: @RichardChambers The linked instructibles article is from July, but since then the API has been completed, well... at least according to espressif's roadmap.

Also my problem is that there are only outdated hacks laying around in forums.